# Обработка символьных ссылок в Java

Tags: java

Хочу написать пару десятков строк кода для пересчета папок и файлов, но столкнулся с такой проблемой:  не срабатывает блок `if(BasicFileAttributes.isSymbolicLink())` при нахождении на симлинк. Вместо этого обрабатывается блок `if(BasicFileAttributes.isDirectory())` и всё зацикливается если симлинк указывает на папку которая уже обработана.

Вопрос: как правильно организовать обработку символьных ссылок?

```
public class Main {

    static long dirsCount = 0;
    static long filesCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File root = new File("/");

        showFiles(root);

        System.out.println("Dirs: " + dirsCount);
        System.out.println("Files: " + filesCount);
    }

    public static void showFiles(File parent) throws IOException {

        File[] chieldFiles = parent.listFiles();

        for (File chield : chieldFiles){
            Path path = Paths.get(chield.toURI());
            BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
            try {
                if (attr.isSymbolicLink()) {
                    System.out.println(chield.getAbsolutePath());
                } else if (attr.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.println(chield.getAbsolutePath());
                    dirsCount++;
                    showFiles(chield);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(chield.getAbsolutePath());
                    filesCount++;
                }
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо добавить третий параметр `LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS` в вызов функции `Files.readAttributes()` иначе все `symlink` возвращаются разрезолвленые, т.е. возвращаются конкретные объекты файловой системы.

```
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: @ВикторМушак не за что. Но лучше не добавлять подобные комментарии. Почитайте эти ссылки [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  -  [Справка > Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)